# Can I use break points on javascript in asp.net mvc3?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to use breakpoint in JavaScript to see the functionality.

Is there any way to do that in asp.net mvc3, I'm using visual studio 2010?

Answer (score 2):

If adding debugger statement does not work and you are using IE, check the advanced settings. You should unselect disable javascript debugging

Answer (score 1):

If you are using IE then you can put in a debugger flag in your javascript,

```
function someJavaScriptMethod(eventSay) {
    debugger;
}
```

Other browsers like Chrome and FireFox have dev tools to allow you to inspect js and put in breakpoints within it.  Up to you what you prefer.

Comment: IE has a Dev toolbar too, its quite useful. it does allow you to put in dynamic breakpoints.

Answer (score 1):

[FireBug](http://getfirebug.com) provides various ways of debugging a javascript part in a webpage - including stop points.